# Error in installing Snapd in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, snap

I tried to install Snap. I cloned it from https://aur.archlinux.org/snapd.git
then I entered `makepkg -si`, but it couldn't retrieve the packages.

```
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (2) apparmor-3.0.0-3  squashfs-tools-4.4-2

Total Download Size:   1.19 MiB
Total Installed Size:  4.24 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'apparmor-3.0.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from arch.jensgutermuth.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'apparmor-3.0.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.kumi.systems : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'apparmor-3.0.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.orbit-os.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'apparmor-3.0.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.ubrco.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'apparmor-3.0.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.chaoticum.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'apparmor-3.0.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from archlinux.dynamict.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'apparmor-3.0.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.myrveln.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
```

and it continued until the end.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your package index is out of date -- the source repositories already have 3.0.1-1. You need to update/upgrade first using `pacman -Syu` (you can also partial upgrade with `pacman -Sy`, but it is not recommended or supported).